# The color in my Final Cut PX Viewer is way off

Tags: video, final-cut-pro

So I have a bunch of clips that I shot at 1080/24p/neutral with my T2i that all look pretty good which I'm trying to import into FCPx to assemble into a short film. When I first got FCPx last week, I was playing around with the color correction on a dummy video clip. Now, for whatever reason, it seems that every clip I import has the same settings applied to it. (I'm pretty sure clips looked normal before doing this, but I'm not 100% sure).

I have tried un-/re-installing FCPx, creating a new project, checking the effects applied, etc. but nothing seems to work. I have checked the original media in the Finder and the color looks perfectly fine, as well as in Quicktime, and on my camera.

What am I doing wrong here? The thumbnails in the Events tab look correct, but when I preview them in the viewer or add them to the timeline, then the color of the clip changes. It's almost as if the viewer is just showing the video incorrectly. I don't quite understand what's going on here. I did a Google search and it sounds like it might have something to do with the Quicktime Player gamma, or the color profiles in Apple Snow Leopard. Any thoughts or suggestions?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The curse of the early adopter! Check your system preferences -> displays -> color. FCX (Its not Pro) might have made a new color profile

Comment: It's strange, because others seem to be having success with it (despite the scathing reviews). Not sure what I did incorrectly.

Comment: I have the same issue. Videos in the preview area (only) are quite a bit darker, but they come out fine after exporting...

Comment: I discovered that it is an issue with my graphics card. I am running FCX on a late 2008 Macbook, which does not have a graphics card that supports the application.

Check HERE: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4664

Comment: I'm running a 2010 MacBook Pro with a 9400M which is supported. Apparently it's got something to do with the colour profile used on the monitor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered that it is an issue with my graphics card. I am running FCX on a late 2008 Macbook, which does not have a graphics card that supports the application.

Check **[HERE](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4664)** to see if yours is supported.